# Specifying index.html in browser to load home page

Tags: html, https

If I want to load the homepage of https://medium.com/ by typing the exact index.html file address into my browser, how would I do that? Or is it not possible?

https://medium.com/index.html gives me a 404 error. Also curious how I would do this more broadly with any webpage for which my browser is displaying a url that does not end in .html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common static websites hosted just as files somewhere usually have an index.html document which can be resolved either directly or is normally loaded when no particular document is specified so `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/index.html` both work.
But this is not how most webs work. Pages can be dynamically generated server side, you just send a request to the server and if the path matches some server operation it will create a response for you. Unless `https://example.com/` returns documents from a directory using something classic like the `Apache Web Server` set to serve static files from a directory, it won't work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to know what, if any, URLs for a given website resolve to duplicates of the homepage (or any other page).

Dynamically generated sites, in particular, tend not to have alternative URLs for pages.